# pandas groupby and get all null rows till the first non null value in multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get all null rows above a value using group by.

So, for example given following dataframe.

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| ID | Start Date | End Date  | Date_D | D-Values | Date_R | R-Values |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | JAN_15 |        - | 15-Jan |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | FEB_15 |        - | 15-Feb |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | MAR_15 |        - | 15-Mar |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | APR_15 |        - | 15-Apr |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | MAY_15 |      -28 | 15-May |    15000 |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | JUN_15 |        - | 15-Jun |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | JUL_15 |        - | 15-Jul |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | AUG_15 |        - | 15-Aug |        - |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

My desired output looks like this.

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| ID | Start Date | End Date  | Date_D | D-Values | Date_R | R-Values |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | FEB_15 |        - | 15-Feb |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | MAR_15 |        - | 15-Mar |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | APR_15 |        - | 15-Apr |        - |
| A  | 2/26/2015  | 5/26/2015 | MAY_15 |      -28 | 15-May |    15000 |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

**EDIT**

There are multiple IDs so need to implement on multiple customers.
Want rows based on start date and end date e.g. start selecting rows from Feb_15 and upto the last non-null value within the date range.

Comment: what if there are more that one value? is `'-'` a NaN? What is the reference column?

Comment: @mozway `-` is NaN, yes there can be more values and rows need to be selected keeping in mind start date and end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`Series.cumprod()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) to check first not null:

```
df[df[['D-Values','R-Values']]
     #.replace('-', np.nan) # if necessary
     .isna()
     .any(axis=1)
     .groupby(df['ID'])
     .cumprod()
     .groupby(df['ID'])
     .shift(fill_value=True)
     .astype(bool) 
    & df['Date_D'].eq('FEB_15')
                  #.groupby(df['ID']) # BY ID
                  .cummax()
                  .eq(1) 
   ]
```

Comment: it works perfectly but initially I forgot to mention that I need to skip Jan_15 and 15-Jan as customer start date is in month of Feb, is it possible you can help in that too?

Comment: so, customer activity starts in Feb and ends in May. I want only these months in Date_D and D-Values and Date_R and R-Values Jan is not required. There can be more months earlier as well

Comment: but that only exclude Jan_15, but if there is Dec_14 or more earlier months... I am sorry should have mentioned it in question clearly

Comment: If your dataframe is sorted you can use `df['Date_D'].eq('FEB_15').cummax().eq(1)` or by ID `df['Date_D'].eq('FEB_15').groupby(df['ID']).cummax().eq(1)` @M_S_N

Comment: can you tell if there is one more non null value below, how can I transform above query to get that as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `transform` with `idxmax`

```
idx = df[['D-Values','R-Values']].notna().all(1).groupby(df["ID"]).transform('idxmax')
out = df[df.index <= idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to remove the last rows with "-", and assuming 'D-values" the reference column.

You can compute a `cummax` on the reversed boolean array:

```
mask = df['D-Values'].ne('-').iloc[::-1].cummax()
# or, for NaNs:
# mask = df['D-Values'].notna().iloc[::-1].cummax()

df2 = df[mask]
```

output:

```
  ID Start Date   End Date  Date_D D-Values  Date_R R-Values
0  A  1/26/2015  5/26/2015  JAN_15        -  15-Jan        -
1  A  1/26/2015  5/26/2015  FEB_15        -  15-Feb        -
2  A  1/26/2015  5/26/2015  MAR_15        -  15-Mar        -
3  A  1/26/2015  5/26/2015  APR_15        -  15-Apr        -
4  A  1/26/2015  5/26/2015  MAY_15      -28  15-May    15000
```